# UIView animated swap views (slide down)

Tags: iphone, animation, view, transition

This is what i have so far. What I am trying to do is make the starting view (startUpView) to switch to the other view (creatNewGameViewController) by sliding down the screen with the new view. All it does now is switch views normally, but i really want that sliding effect. If anyone can spot the error in my code it would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
#import "CreateNewGameViewController.h"
@synthesize createNewGameViewController;
UIButton *mainCreateGame = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[mainCreateGame addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(goToCreateGameViewController)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[mainScroll addSubview:mainCreateGame];
mainCreateGame.frame = CGRectMake(65, 10, 190, 60);

-(void)goToCreateGameViewController{
CreateNewGameViewController *newGame = [[CreateNewGameViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CreateNewGameViewController" bundle:nil];
self.createNewGameViewController = newGame;

CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 2;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction      
                             functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type =kCATransitionMoveIn;


CATransition *transition1 = [CATransition animation];
transition1.duration = 2;
transition1.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction      
                             functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition1.type =kCATransitionMoveIn;
transition1.subtype =kCATransitionFromTop;

transition1.delegate   = self;

[createNewGameViewController.view.layer addAnimation:transition1 forKey:nil];
transition1.subtype =kCATransitionFromTop;

transition1.delegate = self;



[self presentModalViewController:newGame animated:NO];
[self.view insertSubview:newGame.view atIndex:0];

[createNewGameViewController.view.layer addAnimation:transition1 forKey:nil]; 

[newGame release];
```

Comment: Is presentModalViewController: animated: potentially placing the new view on top of the old one? Also, presenting the view and then inserting its view seems somewhat 'hackish'

Answer (score 0):

UIView has a class method called transition from view to view animated, check if that helps and tell me how it was :)

[UiView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

one piece of advice, you should really be using a navigation controller, a storyboard or something like it to do that kind of view transitions because is the proper way to do.

Comment: what do you mean? Im new to this stuff so im not quite sure what (or why) i should use for half of this stuff lol

Comment: the ios sdk is oriented to MVC and it has controllers For changing between screens